# javascript: this != window, properties still undefined

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I was doing a Salesforce trailhead on Javascript, and a question came up about the scope of this.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/understand-javascript-functions?trail_id=learn-to-work-with-javascript

I thought this.hello would be undefined inside the function, because this would point to window, where .name down not exist. But window == this is false, and the log of that object shows it accesses the properties.

So why is this.name undefined?

```
let message = {
  hello: "Hello",
  names: ["Sue", "Joe"],
  showMessage: function () {
    console.log("this, message");
    console.log(window == this);
    console.log(this);
    this.names.forEach(function (name) {
      console.log(this.hello + " " + name);
    });
  }
};
message.showMessage();

/*
false
Object
    hello: "Hello"
    names: (2) ["Sue", "Joe"]
Sue
"undefined Sue"
"undefined Joe"
*/
```

returns:

[image]

online: https://codepen.io/lsag/pen/gOWjyEj

Comment: Because you are using an object primitive instead of a class instance? If you need a `this` that behaves OOP(ish), then write a class, create an instance of that, and you're done. Otherwise, JS's scoping rules are pretty special, and you should [deeply familiarise yourself with how `this` scoping works](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Each `function() {}` has its own `this`, as your function in your `forEach` is different to the showMessage `function`, they both have their own different `this`. Log `this` inside your forEach callback and you'll see `window`

Answer (score 1):

If you use an arrow function in the forEach, you'll get the expected result:

```
let message = {
  hello: "Hello",
  names: ["Sue", "Joe"],
  showMessage: function () {
    console.log("this, message");
    console.log(window == this);
    console.log(this);
    this.names.forEach((name) => {
      console.log(this.hello + " " + name);
    });
  }
};
message.showMessage();
```

That's because arrow functions do not have their own `this` binding, but takes it from the surrounding scope. Your function is not bound to any object, so it takes `window` as its `this`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `this` keyword obtains the context of the function you called. so it would not be equal to the window.

```js
let message = {
  hello: "Hello",
  names: ["Sue", "Joe"],
  showMessage: function () {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

message.showMessage();
```

You can see that this is referred to the object `message` as it is the context of the method `showMessage`.

In the following example, you can see that `this` is referred to the window, since it is inside another function without any previous reference, so it takes `this` from the window:

```js
let message = {
  hello: "Hello",
  names: ["Sue", "Joe"],
  showMessage: function () {
    this.names.forEach(function (name) {
      console.log(this === window);  // referred to the window
    });
  }
};

message.showMessage();
```

To avoid this, just use **arrow functions**:

```js
let message = {
      hello: "Hello",
      names: ["Sue", "Joe"],
      showMessage: function () {
        this.names.forEach((name) => {  // arrow function
          console.log(this.hello + " " + name);  // referred to the object
        });
      }
    };

    message.showMessage();
```

Comment: have a lot to investigate here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up: unless you're already a JS expert, don't use an object literal if you want "object methods and properties" that work the way you'd expect, based on a general knowledge of object oriented programming.

Use a class:

```js
class Message {
  constructor(hello = ``, names = []) {
    this.hello = hello;
    this.names = names.slice();
  }

  showMessage() {
    this.names.forEach(name => console.log(`${this.hello} ${name}`));
  }
}

let message = new Message(`hello`, [`Sue`, `Joe`]);
message.showMessage();
```

Because if you want to insist on object literals, you better understand [how `this` works in JavaScript at a deep level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Also note that all strings use backticks: don't use `'` or `"` in modern JS, use the [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) notation until you know when you shouldn't use them (which will be almost never).

Answer (score 0):

At first glance my head says "Oh it's because it's binding the scope to the new function", but then when I think about it more that doesn't make sense.

```
console.log(window == this);
console.log(this);
```

That "this" was bound to the object scope of "message", not to the function.  So the `showMessage: function ()` declaration has no effect on that scope.  You can also see that in the `console.log(this)` which shows the entire object being logged.

Then the next question is okay, but why then does the next function, `function (name)`, suddenly actually change the scope.  I think this is because it has nothing to do with the function, it's likely because using the forEach created a new scope and not the function.  So the this being used inside that loop is bound to the loop, not the function.

Either that or something else is happening that's way more weird, like javascript ignoring function scope if it's assigned to an object but implementing function scope if it's a function inside another function.  First option sounds more reasonable to me.

But I'm just a speculative idiot.